# mouseover event not firing till clicked on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mouseover, dom-events

I'm trying to run a function when the cursor is over a list item like so:

```
<div id="vue-app">
    <ul>
        <li v-for="item in items" @mouseover="removeItem(item)">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>

new Vue({
    el: '#vue-app',
    data: {
        items: ['meat', 'fruits', 'vegetables'],
    },
    methods: {
        removeItem(value) {
            ...
        }
    },
});
```

however the mouseover event only fires when I click on the list item. What am I not doing correct here?

**MouseOver**

[image]

**MouseClicked**

[image]

Comment: It is working properly, can you share more info  ?

Comment: That's generally all the code, I've added screenshots, not sure if they will help though

Comment: check the working code as answer, I will remove this in some time

Comment: If by any chance you are using a custom component then see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46293996/why-mouseover-action-in-vue-cannot-work

Comment: no, there is no custom  component

Comment: I am seeing the same issue, anyone figure out why this is happening? 
Sometimes if I wait like 20-30 seconds, the event eventually gets triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Check this working code

```js
new Vue({
    el:'#vue-app',
    data:{
        items:['meat','fruits','vegetables'],
    },
    methods:{
        removeItem(value){
          console.log(value);
        }
    },
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.7/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-app">
        <ul>
            <li v-for="item in items" @mouseover="removeItem(item)">{{item}}</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I've noted that the code above and this one does not work on chrome. Tested it on mozilla firefox and it works correctly

Comment: I am using chrome and it is working in chrome also.what version you are using for chrome ?

Comment: Version 72.0.3626.119 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: what if you check above snippet in you current browser ? there must be other issue it is working in this version.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the device toolbar was enabled.  It placed a touch emulation  status bar at the top of my page and my cursor turned into a grey circle. This was preventing mouse events from firing unless I clicked.

Try turning off the device toolbar in developer tools.  On the Mac, with the developer tools window in focus, type cmd + shift + m or click the icon between the select element icon and the Elements menu item.